# pre-commit hook that checks if staged files were modified again

Tags: git, bash, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I am trying to write a git pre-commit hook that checks if files which were staged with `git add` were modified again before committing.

Basically I am interested in these files

```
git status --short
MM test1
AM test2
```

Now the pre-commit hook looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# git pre-commit hook that checks for staged files that were modified.

# exit on error
set -e

# DOES NOT WORK
cached=$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M)

# everything is fine
if ! [[ -n $cached ]]; then
    exit 0
fi

# GNU and BSD versions of xargs behave differently.
if xargs --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    flag="-l" # GNU
else
    flag="-L1" # BSD
fi

printf "The following files have been modified after they have been staged:\n\n"
printf "$cached"
printf "\n\nYou can stage these changes with:\n"
printf " git diff --name-only --cached | xargs ${flag} git add\n"
printf "Aborting commit. Stage the modified files and commit again or skip"
printf " checking with --no-verify (not recommended).\n"

exit 1
```

The problem is, that this hook also picks up files that were modified but not staged. How would I have to adjust my hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with `git diff` you need two passes, one to find files added or modified in the index (`git diff --cached --name-status` or similar), and another to find files modified since the index version (`git diff --name-status` or similar).

But you don't have to do this with `git diff`.  The answer is in your phrase:

> Basically I am interested in these files ...

Just run `git status --short` (or `--porcelain`) and grep for `^[AM]M`: those are your files.  Run the output of this through something to slice off the status part (`cut`, `sed`, etc); those are the names.

The `sed` command can do the matching as well as the cutting, and is lighter weight than `awk`, so is probably the best tool:

```
git status --porcelain | sed -n 's/^[AM]M //p'
```

There is one flaw: for files where `git status` detects a rename or copy operation (`R` and `C` in the left-most column), you can miss some index-vs-work-tree changes.  There's also `D`eleted-in-commit but `M`odified (not deleted) in work-tree.  I'm not sure if you care about these cases.  If so, read through the details in [the `git status` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-status.html) and modify the sed regular expression accordingly.

(There's a separate flaw: if you're in the middle of a merge, `git status` will tell you about the merge.  However, you can't commit until you've finished the merge, so I only mention this in case someone wants to use this same idea in something other than the pre-commit hook.)